# Discover Launch URLs (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to discover launch URLs of installed apps on an iOS device?

(AudioBus does know which apps are installed, somehow, and its "Select Input" box shows just those that are available for input)

Comment: Seems like this might explain what AudioBus is doing:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:

Comment: If those apps are from same developer, then they know. You can get the URL schemes of almost all apps here : http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely what AudioBus does is use `-[UIApplication canOpenURL:]` to check if a URL handler is registered on the device. It requires a list of URL schemes beforehand tho (AudioBus seems to require developers to register apps, as does Facebook), and any app can claim to handle any URL as far as I can tell, so it's never a definitive solution...

Example:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"googlechrome://example.com"]]) {
    // Google Chrome is likely installed on the device
}
```

You might also want to look at inter-app audio introduced with iOS 7 for the topic of sharing audio between apps.

Comment: Great, I'll take this as a "no"